# NVMe drive model data through ioctl

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

Is there a way to retrieve the model number of a NVME drive through a ioctl function call? This is possible for a IDE drive by using the hd_driveid struct defined in /include/linux/hdreg.h.

*hdreg.h*

```
struct hd_driveid{
...
        unsigned short  ecc_bytes;      
        unsigned char   fw_rev[8];      
        unsigned char   model[40];      /*see here*/
        unsigned char   max_multsect;   
...
}
```

I do not see a similar method for retrieving the model of a NVMe drive in /include/linux/nvme_ioctl.h

I fear

Comment: To start, does `lspci -v` show anything? May need `sudo`

Comment: yes, I can see my drive through lspci

Comment: `sudo strace -s0 smartctl -a /dev/nvme0` suggest `ioctl(3, NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD, 0x7ffd5e5e7400) = 0`.

Comment: @AllanWind I believe you are correct. I'll keep this thread updated when, and if, I figure out how to correctly use NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD

Comment: I would look at src for smartctl.

Comment: @AllanWind I'm way ahead of you on this one.
The exact syntax for NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the section 5.15.2.2 of the [1.4 specification](https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVM-Express-1_4-2019.06.10-Ratified.pdf). This should work. I didn't have an NVMe drive to test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/nvme_ioctl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if (fd == 0) {
        perror("open: ");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[4096] = {0};
    struct nvme_admin_cmd mib = {0};
    mib.opcode = 0x06; // identify
    mib.nsid = 0;
    mib.addr = (__u64) buf;
    mib.data_len = sizeof(buf);
    mib.cdw10 = 1; // controller

    int ret = ioctl(fd, NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD, &mib);
    if (ret) {
        perror("ioctl: ");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("SN: %.20s\n", &buf[4]);
    printf("SN: %.40s\n", &buf[24]);
    printf("FW: %.8s\n", &buf[64]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After continuing research I came to the same conclusion.. opcode should be 6 and cdw10 should be 1.
The only place I disagree is the buffer must be 4096 bytes and follow a struct described in:
https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVM-Express-1_4-2019.06.10-Ratified.pdf
See section 5.15.2.2
I have not tested yet. (been pulled in a different direction for now) When I do test I'll update here.